# Checked event not firing sometimes on checkboxes rendered by knockout in chrome

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have create a simple jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/c2wus7qg/3/

Here you will see four list items with checkboxes. If you uncheck any of them the change event **will not** fire. Then if you uncheck the remaining item it **will** fire.

Also if you check any unchecked item and uncheck again the change event will not fire in this case as well.

This seem to happen in chrome only. It works as expected in firefox and safari.

Here are code examples (simplified):

html:

```
<ul>
  <!-- ko foreach: categoriesComputed -->
  <li>
    <input data-bind="attr:{value: id}, checked: state,
                                            event: {change: $root.categoryChanged}" type="checkbox">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

  self.categories = ko.observableArray();

  self.Category = function(id, name, state) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.state = ko.observable(state);
  };

  self.categoriesComputed = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.categories()
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.state() < b.state() ? 1 : -1;
      })
      .slice(0, 4);
  });

  self.categoryChanged = function() {
    console.log('Yep, definitely changed!');
  }
}

var KO = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(KO);

setTimeout(function() {
    var categories = [];
    for ( var i = 1; i <= 20; i++ ) {
    //set state to true only for some elements
    var state = i >= 5 && i <= 6;
    categories.push(new KO.Category(i, 'category #' + i, state));
  }
  KO.categories(categories);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is happening here is that you are unbinding the checkbox before its "change" event can fire. Your computed is only showing the top 4, but as soon as you uncheck one of the options it gets sorted out of those top 4 and removed from the DOM.

If you remove the `.slice(0, 4);` from your computed function you should see the event fire properly each time.

**Edit:**
One possible solution depending on your use-case is to use an array on the root model to store the selected options rather than a state observable on each individual option.

```
self.selectedCategories = ko.observableArray([5,6]);
```

The checked binding will use the array to store the selected models, or, when paired with the checkedValue binding will use the array to store just that property value of the selected option. For example if you use:

```
<input data-bind="attr:{value: id}, checked: $root.selectedCategories, checkedValue: id" type="checkbox">
```

the selectedCategories array will contain the IDs of the option objects (5 and 6 to begin with).

This way you can create a single subscription on that observable array to watch for changes to any of the checkboxes, and bypass the event binding which relies on the model being rendered in the DOM.

```
  self.categoryChanged = function() {
    console.log('Yep, definitely changed!');
  }
  self.selectedCategories.subscribe(self.categoryChanged);
```

Of course your sort function will have to be updated as well to check if an element exists in the selected array rather than checking the "state" of the object. that could look something like:

```
function(a, b) {
    var indexA = self.selectedCategories().indexOf(a.id);
    var indexB = self.selectedCategories().indexOf(b.id);
    if(indexB == indexA){
        return Number(a.id) - Number(b.id);
    } else { 
        return indexB - indexA;
    }
}
```

Example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2wus7qg/5/)

Comment: @KingJulien Added an example of one potential solution

Answer (score 0):

It is a timing issue (as Jason noted), with the DOM being updated before the change event can fire. I modified your code to add an `echoState` member that gets the value of `state` after a brief delay. I based `categoriesComputed` on this, with the result being that the DOM isn't updated before the change event can fire.

I doubt this is useful for any real-world situations. :)

```js
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.categories = ko.observableArray();

  self.Category = function(id, name, state) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.state = ko.observable(state);
    this.echoState = ko.observable(state);

    this.state.subscribe((newValue) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.echoState(newValue)
      }, 0);
    });
  };

  self.categoriesComputed = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.categories
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.echoState() < b.echoState() ? 1 : -1;
      })
      .slice(0, 4);
  });

  self.categoryChanged = function(data) {
    console.log('Yep, definitely changed!', data);
  }
}

var KO = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(KO);

setTimeout(function() {
  var categories = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    //set state to true only for some elements
    var state = i >= 5 && i <= 6;
    categories.push(new KO.Category(i, 'category #' + i, state));
  }
  KO.categories(categories);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
Uncheck any of first two checkboxes and the change event won't fire!
<ul>
  <!-- ko foreach: categoriesComputed -->
  <li>
    <input data-bind="attr:{value: id}, checked: state,
           event: {change: $root.categoryChanged}" type="checkbox">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```